# How to save server responses to a dynamic variable

Tags: r

datasets_uids <- c("b0ozQvcc7nP","D9CrlbX7KBV")

servers <- c("url1","url2")

```
for (i in 1:length(datasets_uids)) {
  
  for(j in 1:length(servers)){
    
    assign(paste("postOrgUnitsToDataset",j,sep="_"),httr::POST(paste0(servers[j],"dhis/api/dataSets/",datasets_uids[i],"/organisationUnits"),                                       body=httr::upload_file("file.json"),
                                      httr::verbose(),
                                      httr::authenticate("username","password", type = "basic"),
                                      httr::content_type("application/json"),
                                      httr::progress("up"),
                                      httr::set_config(httr::config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
    ))
  }
}
```

I want all the four responses to be saved as below

```
postOrgUnitsToDataset_1=response1
postOrgUnitsToDataset_2=response2
postOrgUnitsToDataset_3=response3
postOrgUnitsToDataset_4=response4
```

But the responses are being overwritten and saved in two responses as below

```
postOrgUnitsToDataset_1=response3
postOrgUnitsToDataset_2=response4
```

So how do I modify my code above to have all the responses saved in `postOrgUnitsToDataset_1,postOrgUnitsToDataset_2,postOrgUnitsToDataset_3,postOrgUnitsToDataset_4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to create global variables with `assign`. It's much easier to work with data in lists in R. One way to iterate to create a list is `lapply`. Here we first create all the URLs and then send a request for each

```
datasets_uids <- c("b0ozQvcc7nP","D9CrlbX7KBV")
servers <- c("url1","url2")

requests <- expand.grid(uid=datasets_uids, server=servers) |>
  transform(url=paste0(server,"dhis/api/dataSets/",uid,"/organisationUnits"))

postOrgUnitsToDataset <- lapply(requests$url, function(url) {
  httr::POST(url,
     body=httr::upload_file("file.json"),
     httr::verbose(),
     httr::authenticate("username","password", type = "basic"),
     httr::content_type("application/json"),
     httr::progress("up"),
     httr::set_config(httr::config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
)})
```

Then all the data will be in `postOrgUnitsToDataset[[1]]`, `postOrgUnitsToDataset[[2]]`, etc. It will be in the same order as the records are shown in the `requests` data.frame

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick. Though I have added as.character(request$url) and the piping operator(%>%) to the code